# Git Remote showing but does not exist

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, git-remote

I am trying to use my git repo within Visual Studio. I can with no problems in other machines, but when I try adding it to Visual Studio in my machine, I get the following error:

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIbmX.png)

When I use git separately on command-line, I have no issues.

While observing my repository, I found out a very strange behaviour. When I run a "git remote -v" command, this is what I get:

[git remote screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91c8v.png)

However, I have never created a git remote named "hub". I suspect this is the inconsistence which is causing Visual Studio not to understand my repository. When I try to remove "hub", I receive a message that it doesn't exist:

[git remote rm screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3OCL.png)

Does anyone know where this "broken reference" is logged, and how to do in order to remove it? I'm suspecting it has nothing to do with my repo...

I have already tried uninstalling git and re-installing it on my machine.

Comment: Perhaps also Check with 'git remote show hub'?

Comment: And `git config --list --show-origin` could give additional information. See information about remotes there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your system file manager / explorer, show hidden files and go to the following file:

```
[YOUR-REPO-PATH]/.git/config
```

Remove references to the `hub`